# Pandas convert a column containing strings into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe with columns that contains comma separated strings. I would like to create new columns similar to what one hot encoding does.

Below is a very simplistic example. In my use case, I have thousands of rows with more columns, and two columns containing comma separated many strings. I could have used apply+lamda function+string contains condition to create each column but that is very tedious as it will be 100s of new columns

Input Datafarme

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
 1         {"alpha", "bravo"} 
 2         {"bravo", "charlie"}
 3         {"alpha", "charlie","gama"}
 4         {"bravo", "charlie","delta"}
```

Output dataframe

```
ColumnA    alpha     bravo   charlie delta gamma  
 1         1         1       0       0     0       
 2         0         1       0       0     0
 3         1         0       1       0     1
 4         0         1       1       1     0
```

**edit:**
I should have mentioned that the data is read from csv file. Column B is is of type str. It contains many strings inside. it looks {"value1" , "value2"...."valueN"} here values could be of the format "XYZ" or "X Y Z" or "X_Y_Z". The example i have provided is very simplistic version

Comment: Doesn't look like comma separated strings, are the `{`/`"`/`}` part of the string? What is the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the data is read from csv file. So no the column B is is of type str. with many strings inside. it looks {"value1" , "value2"...."valueN"} here values could be of the format "XYZ" or "X Y Z" or "X_Y_Z"

Comment: So, do the solutions below work for you? If not, you should provide more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really have string representations of sets, first remove the `{"`/`"}` and internal `", "`, then use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies):

```
out = (df.drop(columns='ColumnB')
         .join(df['ColumnB'].str.replace('^{"|"(,)\s*"|"}$', r'\1', regex=True)
                            .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
               )
        )
```

Output:

```
   ColumnA  alpha  bravo  charlie  delta  gama
0        1      1      1        0      0     0
1        2      0      1        1      0     0
2        3      1      0        1      0     1
3        4      0      1        1      1     0
```

##### Alternative

similar to @PaulS's approach, but with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
s = df['ColumnB'].apply(literal_eval).explode()
out = df.drop(columns='ColumnB').join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

Comment: You way is also very nice, @mozway. +1.

Comment: @PaulS the first one also has flaws if there are other types of quotes, or internal commas. The second one (similar to yours) should be more robust (provided the syntax is valid!)

Comment: @mozway given my edit and response to your comment. will your solution still work?

Comment: Can you update the example adding a variety of the possibilities and the expected output? I believe it should work, but why don't you test on the real data and give us feedback?

Comment: @mozway both solutions work, first seems to perform faster than the second one though. Can you please elaborate a bit on what your regex is doing in ```str.replace```

Comment: @KhurramMajeed it's removing the leading `{"` and trailing `"}` and replacing all the internal `", "` by `,`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
aux = df['ColumnB'].str.extractall(r'"(.*?)"').droplevel(1)
pd.concat([df['ColumnA'], pd.crosstab(aux.index, aux[0])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ColumnA  alpha  bravo  charlie  delta  gama
0        1      1      1        0      0     0
1        2      0      1        1      0     0
2        3      1      0        1      0     1
3        4      0      1        1      1     0
```

Comment: Nice one, but only works with full words ;) +1 *NB. don't `reset_index`, rather `droplevel(1)` as you want to keep the original level in case this is not a range index.*

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my answer! You are right: my approach does not work if, between quotes, there is spaces. I am going to try to improve that.

Comment: @mozway: I guess that my current solution can deal with cases like the ones you pointed out (`{"alpha xyz", "bravo"}`. Thanks for your feedback!